# How to shutdown vertx httpserver programmatically?

Tags: java, vert.x

I created the vertx httpserver by following java code,

```
HttpServer htttpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
htttpServer.setReceiveBufferSize(4 * 1024);
htttpServer.setSendBufferSize(4 * 1024)
    .requestHandler(routeMatcher)
    .listen(portNo, hostname);
```

I placed this server code in one my verticle(RestVerticle.java) when i deploy the verticle it starts the server and i am able to see the port is occupied. Now I want to shut down the httpserver programmatically instead of simply pressing ctrl + c. Kindly help me rectify this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically close the HTTP server.

```
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
server.listen(Config.getInt("HTTP_PORT"));
// To stop the server:
server.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Niraj, I have main method(which is inside StartApp.java) which deploys all related verticles. let say, I create a http server inside RestVerticle.java. Now, how can i stop the service inside StartApp.java file, as i create http server instance into RestVerticle.java file. Because, we should say server.close() with the same instance right?

Comment: Yes, but I guess the challenge should be that how will you call `server.close()`? As you are running the jar file from terminal

Comment: So only, I did one quick fix that I found the process id of that port and killing it through java code. is it a optimal solution for my requirement?